# Принудительное завершение дочернего процесса из родителя в fork() в си

Tags: c, процесс

Возможно ли завершить дочерний процесс не дожидаясь его окончания с помощью функции `wait()`? Например, как завершить вот такой дочерний процесс:

```
pid_t pid;
switch(pid=fork()) {
case 0:
  for(;;){}
default:
  //здесь код, который завершает дочерний процесс
  return 0;
```

P.S. Если вы знаете какой-то адекватный, не сильно мудреный материал по `fork()`, где можно почерпнуть теоретические знания, то направьте меня, пжл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Жестокий метод:

```
kill(pid, SIGKILL);
```

Или более мягко:

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM);
```

В первом случае дочерний процесс будет просто убит, во втором получит сигнал, который может обработать. Но `SIGKILL` убъёт процесс гарантированно, а в случае `SIGTERM` процесс может отказаться заканчивать работу.

В приведённом коде, поскольку процесс, похоже, не содержит обработчиков сигналов, можно использовать любой метод, поскольку, как верно указал на мою ошибку @avp, `SIGTERM` при отсутствии обработчика также убьёт процесс.

Comment: Ок, я понял. А по поводу обработки сигналов можете прояснить? Что и где нужно вызвать, чтобы послать сигнал из процесса в процесс и обработать его?

Comment: Если обработчика нет, то SIGTERM также завершит процесс. Посмотрите в [man signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) колонку `Action` в секции `Standard signals` (и поправьте ответ)

Comment: @avp Спасибо. Исправил свою ошибку.

Comment: @Shadr Посмотрите, например, здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/141206/ю Вроде, понятно описано.